# Sonar Multicore

Tags: sonarqube

I'm just wondering if there's anyway to let sonar use multiple cores when analyzing the code.

Or if there's any other ways to improve performance overall.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of delays do you experience?

Comment: Well not really delays, it's just slow that's all, we gotta run it on loads of different projects with a lot of files, so I was hoping that if it were to use more then 1 core it would make things faster

Answer (score 1):

At the moment most of the analyzers sonar uses are single threaded. I suggested to analyse several plugins parallel. https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3025

You can vote if you want, but at the moment there is no way to use all cores. If you have many projects you could just analyse them in parallel manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the sonar process is mult-threaded it's unlikely the runner can take major advantage of your multi-core machine.

The biggest performance boosts I can recommend are:

- Run your build on the same machine as the Sonar database. JDBC calls across a WAN network can seriously affect your Sonar build times.
- If you use the views plugin consider reducing the number of views. This creates lots of extra JDBC calls.