# Can Sonar Scanner be run on multiple cores?

Tags: multithreading, sonarqube, openedge, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube 6.7.1. Sonar Scanner 3.0.3.778. Sonar Scanner plugin 2.6.1 for jenkins. Postgres 9.6.6 database. Everything is running on one Solaris 11 Unix box. Project language is OpenEdge ABL. I found no mention of running the scanner on multiple cores anywhere in the documentation.

A question on here from 2012 seems to indicate it could not be run on multiple cores. 
[Sonar Multicore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861969/sonar-multicore)

Another question circa 2015 determined that the scanner cannot take advantage of maven's multithread builds.
[Maven Sonarqube Plugin: Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877051/maven-sonarqube-plugin-multithreading)

It seems that one plugin (SonarCFamily) offers a way to scan projects on multiple cores, though our application is not written in C. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Multithreaded+Code+Scan

My interest is in speeding up the sonar scanner analysis. Analysis for our (admittedly large ~1 million line) codebase took a full 24 hours. Only plugin installed is the base openedge language plugin. Only default OpenEdge rules are active.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there any code you'd like people to look at?
Have you thought or tried to wrap the call to the scanner (assuming if it's fired from OpenEdge, you didn't specify) in threads and have multiple starting points?

Comment: Just as reference material - our 4 million line codebase takes just over an hour. The scanner is running on a Windows 2012 R2 VM, SonarQube 6.5.0.27846 is still running with the embedded evaluation database on a CentOS 7.3 VM. We are /not/ using the Jenkins scanner but starting it from an Ant target.